# wso2 identity server Identify a particular session in browser

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm Developing a Oauth Authentication based Web Application Where the user is logged in chrome, Edge and Firefox browsers. I get the list of active sessions(chrome,edge and firefox using agent parser) in Active session API response. But my requirement here is i want to display the current session in my web application as chrome only if the user's current session is in chrome and simultaneously i have to display current session as edge only if the user has logged in Edge and same for firefox. how will i be able to differentiate between the user's current browser session in the response. Any help would be highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you correctly, you want to obtain users browser name right? if yes, you can get it from the user-agent header.

Comment: I can get the browser name through user agent, but i want to display the browser name exactly which the user is logged in currently. if he has logged in chrome only i have to display only chrome